# Tensorflow Lite: ResNet example model gave VERY poor result during validation with ImageNet

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, resnet, imagenet

I am studying tensorflow lite. I downloaded the ResNet frozen graph *ResNet_V2_101* from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/models.md#image-classification-float-models .

And then I followed https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/tutorials/post_training_quant.ipynb to convert this frozen graph to both Lite model and quantized lite model.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib
import sys
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants
import time
graph_def_file = "resnet_saved_model/resnet_v2_101_299_frozen.pb"
input_arrays = ["input"]
output_arrays = ["output"]
converter = tf.lite.TocoConverter.from_frozen_graph(str(graph_def_file),input_arrays,output_arrays,input_shapes = {"input":[1,299,299,3]})
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("saved_model/resnet_v2_101_299_frozen.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model) 

converter.post_training_quantize = True
tflite_quantized_model = converter.convert()
open("saved_model/resnet_v2_101_299_frozen_quantize.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_quantized_model)
```

Then I followed https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/tools/accuracy/ilsvrc to evalute its accuracy using ImageNet Validation Dataset (50000 images) on my desktop.

However, when I run

```
bazel run -c opt   --cxxopt='--std=c++11'   --   //tensorflow/lite/tools/accuracy/ilsvrc:imagenet_accuracy_eval   --model_file="/home/kathy/saved_model/ResNet_V2_101.tflite"   --ground_truth_images_path="/media/kathy/Documents/val_imgs"   --ground_truth_labels="/home/kathy/workspace/tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/tools/accuracy/ilsvrc/VALIDATION_LABELS.txt"   --model_output_labels="/home/kathy/workspace/tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/tools/accuracy/ilsvrc/resnet_output_labels.txt"   --output_file_path="/tmp/accuracy_output.txt" --num_images=0
```

and checked the output `accuracy_output.txt`. The accuracy is very poor. I can capture some results among the 50000 images.

```
Top 1, Top 2, Top 3, Top 4, Top 5, Top 6, Top 7, Top 8, Top 9, Top 10
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 25.000, 25.000, 25.000, 25.000, 25.000, 25.000, 25.000
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 20.000, 20.000, 20.000, 20.000, 20.000, 20.000, 20.000
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 16.667, 16.667, 16.667, 16.667, 16.667, 16.667, 16.667
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 14.286, 14.286, 14.286, 14.286, 14.286, 14.286, 14.286
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 12.500, 12.500, 12.500, 12.500, 12.500, 12.500, 12.500
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 11.111, 11.111, 11.111, 11.111, 11.111, 11.111, 11.111
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 10.000, 10.000, 10.000, 10.000, 10.000, 10.000, 10.000
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 9.091, 9.091, 9.091, 9.091, 9.091, 9.091, 9.091
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 8.333, 8.333, 8.333, 8.333, 8.333, 8.333, 8.333
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 7.692, 7.692, 7.692, 7.692, 7.692, 7.692, 7.692
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 7.143, 7.143, 7.143, 7.143, 7.143, 7.143, 7.143
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 6.667, 6.667, 6.667, 6.667, 6.667, 6.667, 6.667
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 6.250, 6.250, 6.250, 6.250, 6.250, 6.250, 6.250
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 5.882, 5.882, 5.882, 5.882, 5.882, 5.882, 5.882
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 5.556, 5.556, 5.556, 5.556, 5.556, 5.556, 5.556
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 5.263, 5.263, 5.263, 5.263, 5.263, 5.263, 5.263
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000, 5.000
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 4.762, 4.762, 4.762, 4.762, 4.762, 4.762, 4.762
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 4.545, 4.545, 4.545, 4.545, 4.545, 4.545, 4.545
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 4.348, 4.348, 4.348, 4.348, 4.348, 4.348, 4.348
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 4.167, 4.167, 4.167, 4.167, 4.167, 4.167, 4.167
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 4.000, 4.000, 4.000, 4.000, 4.000, 4.000, 4.000
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 3.846, 3.846, 3.846, 3.846, 3.846, 3.846, 3.846
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 3.704, 3.704, 3.704, 3.704, 3.704, 3.704, 3.704
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 3.571, 3.571, 3.571, 3.571, 3.571, 3.571, 3.571
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 3.448, 3.448, 3.448, 3.448, 3.448, 3.448, 3.448
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 3.333, 3.333, 3.333, 3.333, 3.333, 3.333, 3.333
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 3.226, 3.226, 3.226, 3.226, 3.226, 3.226, 3.226
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 3.125, 3.125, 3.125, 3.125, 3.125, 3.125, 3.125
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 3.030, 3.030, 3.030, 3.030, 3.030, 3.030, 3.030
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 2.941, 2.941, 2.941, 2.941, 2.941, 2.941, 2.941
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 2.857, 2.857, 2.857, 2.857, 2.857, 2.857, 2.857
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 2.778, 2.778, 2.778, 2.778, 2.778, 2.778, 2.778
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 2.703, 2.703, 2.703, 2.703, 2.703, 2.703, 2.703
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 2.632, 2.632, 2.632, 2.632, 2.632, 2.632, 2.632
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 2.564, 2.564, 2.564, 2.564, 2.564, 2.564, 2.564
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 2.500, 2.500, 2.500, 2.500, 2.500, 2.500, 2.500
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 2.439, 2.439, 2.439, 2.439, 2.439, 2.439, 2.439
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 2.381, 2.381, 2.381, 2.381, 2.381, 2.381, 2.381
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 2.326, 2.326, 2.326, 2.326, 2.326, 2.326, 2.326
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 2.273, 2.273, 2.273, 2.273, 2.273, 2.273, 2.273
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 2.222, 2.222, 2.222, 2.222, 2.222, 2.222, 2.222
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 2.174, 2.174, 2.174, 2.174, 2.174, 2.174, 2.174
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 2.128, 2.128, 2.128, 2.128, 2.128, 2.128, 2.128
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 2.083, 2.083, 2.083, 2.083, 2.083, 2.083, 2.083
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 2.041, 2.041, 2.041, 2.041, 2.041, 2.041, 2.041
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 2.000, 2.000, 2.000, 2.000, 2.000, 2.000, 2.000
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.961, 1.961, 1.961, 1.961, 1.961, 1.961, 1.961
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.923, 1.923, 1.923, 1.923, 1.923, 1.923, 1.923
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.887, 1.887, 1.887, 1.887, 1.887, 1.887, 1.887
```

However, according to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/tutorials/post_training_quant.ipynb, the top-1 accuracy can reach 76.8 but my attempt even cannot reach 1 in the end. 
Why this happens? Where I did wrong? Thanks!

Comment: "but my attempt even cannot reach 1 in the end". What do you get in the end? ~0.7 or...

Comment: @prosti After 50000 images, my results from top-1 to top-10 are 0.080, 0.146, 0.230, 0.324, 0.408, 0.518, 0.608, 0.678, 0.770, 0.888. They are already in percentage.

Comment: strange, the item with 0.888 is category that is most probable. Is your output from top-1 to top-10? You could pass it through the `softmax` layer to get the final probabilities. Then the sum of all output channels should be =1

Comment: @prosti  Yes. This output is from top-1 to top-10 after running 50000 images. But I didn't write any customized code so far. I just followed all the introductions in the links and run everything directly. I can look into the sample code to try what you suggested. But I just don't understand why the examples gave this poor result...

Comment: @prosti I think I fix it. I use the wrong category labels...This is a very stupid mistake. But thank you for your advice all the same!

Comment: We did it. I will add an answer for the rest of the world based on your words. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please also check your category labels. In case wrong category labels have been used the results would be as you described.

Answer (score 0):

Check your model path, in your Python code, it is resnet_v2_101_299_frozen_quantize.tflite but you used a different one ResNet_V2_101.tflite in command line